# How to add data from multiple rows based on a column with specific identifiers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have student data and I need to calculate the total number of minutes each student is receiving but there are multiple rows for each student.  The data looks like this:

```
Student      Service        Minutes
1            a              10
1            b              30
2            e              45
2            h              15
2            a              10
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including the code they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ...and to get you started on "what you have tried" look into the excel help on `countif` and `countifs.`  Or you could use a pivot table.